# Data Store with multiple shard keys

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, bigdata, datastore

I've been researching several different data store technologies that can be used for storing huge amounts of semi-structured logs for people to search through later. I've looked at cassandra, riak, and elastic search so far, and it seems like elastic search offers the closest fit for what I'm interested in (largely because it indexes everything transparently). However, there's one feature that I'm interested in that seems to escape them all, and I was wondering if there is a data store with this feature.

What I'm thinking about is the ability to transparent shard on multiple key. To be clear, I'm **not** talking about using a composite key for sharding. I mean that if you had a table that was sharded by `user_id`, `time_of_creation`, and `ip_address`, and you inserted a row, three copies of that row would be created, each one in a different cluster that's sharded by a different key (or maybe they could all somehow actually be in the same cluster. That important part is that the data would be duplicated). And when you wanted to query this table later, the data store would transparently choose which cluster to use.

In the articles I've read about Cassandra, people often recommend doing something like this, but it's definitely a manual process in at least three ways:

- For insertion, you have you insert into each table yourself.
- When it comes to querying, you have to figure out which table you want to query (you need to pick the one that uses the right cluster key).
- And, if you ever want to add another key to shard on, you have to write a routine the existing data into the new table.

Although I was using cassandra as an example, I believe that the situation with riak and elastic search is similar. I understand that a data store that offered this ability would probably have to make huge trades to do so. Updating/deleting might no longer be possible (or it would have extremely poor performance), and consistency would suffer. But, it's a set of trades that I find acceptable when dealing with logs, so I was wondering if anyone is familiar with a technology that offers this feature.

Comment: Why do you want the same data in three "places" because I don't understand? What's the use case for this three copies of the same data?

Comment: You get more efficient queries when you read the data back out. You could do a search that filters by any of the columns the data is sharded on, and you would get the benefit of sharding. It's a pretty common design to do this with cassandra: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

Comment: This is ES, not Cassandra. I am asking you what is the use case you want to cover? You mention columns and sharding. These words are not usually used with Elasticsearch. So, what do you want to achieve with ES describe a practical use case  you believe "sharding" (ES uses the notion of shard, what is the relationship with sharding) and "columns" would fix?

Comment: In elastic search, the concept I'm describing is called [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html](routing). In any data store technology, this practice allows queries that references the key used for sharding to only execute on one server, rather than having to aggregate the results from all the servers. As an example, if it was extremely common for a query to filter by `user_id` or `ip_address` (but not necessarily both), then it would be helpful to be able to shard by both of these keys.

Comment: Ok. Why do you think you need `routing`? There are few use cases that need this kind of feature (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shared-index.html). And if you think that running data on multiple servers/nodes and then aggregate that data on another server/node is  problematic, this is true nature and power of Elasticsearch and it's been built with very idea in mind from the beginning: split the data among nodes, all the nodes perform a "part" of the larger job, then the data is aggregated and returned to the user.

Comment: Routing by a certain value means that all documents that have the same `routing value` end up being indexed in the same `shard` (not same server/node, that's a difference). This is the case for parent/child relationships in ES. Also, if a certain use cases requires it, routing is being used. Otherwise, you need to think about your use case from ES perspective, not from a-general-db-approach general use case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the server/node distinction. It sounds like what I want cannot be done with ES, but I'll keep thinking more about the best way to model it in ES (since I think that's what I'll end up going with).